# How to assign NULL value to a string and then insert it in mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, xampp, netbeans-8

Here I'am calculating the average of one column
If the avg comes to be 0.0, then i would want to assign the string variable as `NULL` else the avg value itself.

These values are getting stored in mysql db
Now my problem is that when the avg does come 0.0, string  NULL gets stored but i want the default NULL value to get stored in it.

How can i assign NULL (and not string NULL) to variable ans??

```
private void btnAdd1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:
     Connection conn = null;
            Statement st = null;          
            ResultSet rs = null;

        try{

  conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/check","root","");
    st = conn.createStatement();

    String sql4 =("SELECT AVG(unit4) as num FROM lo where unit4 IS NOT NULL");
         PreparedStatement pstmt3 = conn.prepareStatement(sql4);
         ResultSet rs4 = pstmt3.executeQuery();
     rs4.next();
     double a3 = rs4.getDouble("num");
     double b3 = Math.round(a3*10);
     double res5 = b3/10;
     rs4.next();
     avg1.setText(String.valueOf(res5));
     String a1 =avg1.getText();
     String ans ;

    if(a1.equals("0.0")){
        ans = null;
    }else{
        ans = a1;
    }

    String query = "INSERT INTO chk(id) VALUES ('"+ans+"')";
    executeSQlQuery(query, "Inserted");

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setNull()` and to avoid any syntax error or SQL Injection you have to use PreparedStatement instead :

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO chk(id) VALUES (?)");
ps.setNull(1, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
ps.executeUpdate();
```

**Note**

Something wired in your program, why you are using `rs4.next();` what if your result is empty, i think you need something like this instead :

```
if (rs4.next()) {//<<<--------------------
    double a3 = rs4.getDouble("num");
    //-----------^^-----------------
}
```

Comment: I agree, but here i need all the values in string  variable first .I would we using prepared statement later.

Comment: so is there no way to assign NULL to variable string ans?

Comment: @SnehaP what purpose to use null in your id?

Comment: what type of `id` int, varchar, or real or what? @SnehaP

Answer (score 0):

You have not enclose `ans` between quotes to handle the `NULL` case. 
Otherwise, indeed you insert `"NULL"` `String` :

```
String query = "INSERT INTO chk(id) VALUES ('"+ans+"')";
```

You can try :

```
String query = "INSERT INTO chk(id) VALUES ("+ ans +")";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is pretty suboptimal, since you're not even using a `PreparedStatement`. Since your query contains the `''` markers, it will always insert a string in the database. In the case of `null` you'll just be inserting `'null'` which isn't what you want.

Now, this is not a good solution, but it's the quickest for you. Modify the query to `"INSERT INTO chk(id) VALUES ("+ans+")"`, and add the following before executing the query:

```
if(ans != null)
    ans = "'" + ans + "'";
```

Remember, this is bad code. It's not the standard way. It has security issues. Learn to use a `PreparedStatement`.